# Conflicts between the parenthetical plural (s) and (s) AutoCorrected to §

Tags: microsoft-word, autocomplete

MS Word includes an AutoCorrect entry for replacing `(s)` with the section symbol: §.

However, it is also common to use the parenthetical plural (`(s)` also referred to as "optional s" or "plural s"), at the end of a noun to indicate that the noun could be either singular or plural. For example: `dog(s), cat(s)`

Naturally, these two uses of `(s)` conflict. Of course, as with any AutoCorrect entry, if you hit the [Backspace] key immediately after, the auto-correction will be undone, but the extra key stroke should be unnecessary. Note that I regularly use both the § symbol and  the parenthetical plural in my documents, so disabling the AutoCorrect entry is not an option. They must both work without requiring any extra key strokes. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the AutoCorrect entry to use a different shortcut. For example: `[s]`.

The § symbol, the ® symbol, and a few others are special in that they do not require a space to be typed to activate them. In fact, the "Plain text"/"Formatted text" options are greyed out in the AutoCorrect Options dialog box. Trying to "add" a new entry with `[s]` won't exhibit that same behavior (a space would be required to activate). At least I've never been able to get it to work that way.

The trick is to *edit* the existing entry. In **Word 2013** take the following steps:

1. Open the dialog box. From the toolbar select [Insert][AutoCorrect Options].
2. Locate the `(s)` entry and select it. Unless you have added your own entries which sort higher, it should be the third item after `(c)` and `(r)`.
3. In the "Replace" field edit the text to read `[s]` (leave the "with" field unchanged) and click [Add].

   [image: Add square bracket entry]

   Note that this only adds a new entry. It does not remove/replace the existing entry. However, it does copy all of the behavior of the existing entry including the fact that a follow-up space is not required.
4. Scroll back up to the original `(s)` entry, select it, and click [Delete].

   [image: Delete old entry]
5. Click the [OK] button and test that things work correctly.

Now, typing `[s]` should AutoCorrect to § and `(s)` will be left as-is.

If you ever want to restore the old behavior, simply edit the AutoCorrect entry in reverse (change `[s]` back to `(s)` and delete the `[s]` entry).